# Username & password string comparison problem

Tags: java

When I enter "abcd" in the passwordField, and use System.out.println(s21) - to check the password - it shows "[C@1372a1a", why?

```
  private void submit() {
    String s1 = userNameField.getText();
    char[] s2 = passwordField.getPassword();
    String s21 = s2.toString();


    if (s1.equals(management.getUsernamesAdmin())&& s21.equals(management.getPasswordsAdmin())) {
        SystemManagementPage admin = new SystemManagementPage(this, true, management);
        admin.setVisible(true);
        }
    } 
    }
```

Comment: What's `passwordField.getPassword()` returning?

Comment: returns the password which the user enter.

Comment: Could you please refine the title of your question? I'm afraid it covers about 99% of question on SO :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
String s21 = s2.toString();
```

This is calling `toString()` on a `char[]`, and isn't going to return anything useful.  Instead,

```
String s21 = new String(s2);
```

Will give you a String composed of the characters in the array.

Other than that, I can't see any reason your code shouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
char[] s2 = passwordField.getPassword();
String s21 = s2.toString();
```

s2 is an Object of type char[]

s2.toString() returns the string representation of the s2 object, as implemented by [java.lang.Object](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

... getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

- after performing `String s21 = s2.toString();` what is the value of s21?
- check with a debugger whether you reach that line inside the if condition `SystemManagementPage admin = new SystemManagementPage(this, true, management);` While you assume the password value is the problem, problem might be at `admin.setVisible(true);` or anywhere else.
- Make sure your passwords are stored in clear text, since this is what you are trying to do here compare them directly and not their hash or encrypted value.
- Make sure your using same case `Admin != admin`
- Does your `passwordField` has a `.getText()` method as well?